# Eigenvalue of $m \times n$ matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am unable to solve this problem from matrix computation book by Gene H. Golub.

Show that if $A$ and $B^H$ are in $\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ with $m\geq n$, then
$\lambda(AB)$ = $\lambda(BA) \cup$ 
$\underbrace{\{0,...,0\}}_\text{m-n}$

Kindly help me solve this problem